# Delete all lines which contain a duplicate word

Tags: powershell, duplicates, grouping

I want to delete all the lines that contain one string and keep just the last line.

Eg:

a 1 
a 2  
a 3 
b 1 
b 2

I want to delete: 
a 1
 a 2 
 b 1 
 
and keep only the last lines: 
 a 3 
 b 2.

I have tried something in powershell but witout success:

```
gc 1.txt | sort | get-unique
```

Comment: Are the numbers in the file or is that you just visually counting the strings for us? When you say "one string," do you mean one sequence of characters with no white space?

Comment: Also, why do you want to keep ("a 3", "b 1") and not ("a 3", "b 2") or ("a 1", "b 1")?

Comment: in the file are numbers and characters , i am just visualizing the strings for you. There are also spaces into the rows, like 2 strings on the same raw. I want to keep only the last rows in the sequence like a 3 and b 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to:

- consider lines that share the same word at the start (`a` or `b` in your example) as group,
- and return the last line from each such group,

use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content 1.txt | Group-Object { (-split $_)[0] } | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[-1] }
```

- `{ (-split $_)[0] }` uses a property *expression*, via a script block (`{ ... }`, rather than a property *name* as the grouping criterion.
- `-split $_` splits each input line (`$_`) into an array of substrings by *whitespace*.
- `(...)[0]` extracts the 1st token, i.e. the first whitespace-separated token on the line (`a` or `b`, in your sample data)

---

As for **what you tried** (showing your command with aliases expanded):

> `Get-Content 1.txt | Sort-Object | Get-Unique`

Your `Sort-Object` and `Get-Unique` calls both operate on the *full lines*, which is not your intent: since all lines are unique when considered *in full*, they are *all* output.

Note that `Sort-Object` has a `-Unique` switch, so the following would come *closer* to what you want, but it wouldn't allow you to control *which* of the lines that share the same first word to return:

```
# !! INCORRECT, because you don't control which of the duplicates
# !! is returned, given that sorting is based on only the *first* word
# !! on each line.
PS> Get-Content 1.txt | Sort-Object { (-split $_)[0] } -Unique
a 1
b 1
```